# What is wrong with my Ajax code in my case using ASP.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I have data like this

```
[{"billno":"111","amount":"2233.00"},{"billno":"222","amount":"2500.00"},{"billno":"333","amount":"3000.00"}]
```

I want to store this record in my database, So before that I am trying to send this records to server

**Here is my AJAX code:**

```
$('#btnAddVendor').click(function () {


    var values = [];

    $('table#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1 input.checkBoxClass:checked').each(function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
        values.push({ 'billno': $row.eq(1).text(), 'amount': $row.eq(5).text() });
    });

    //html_data = JSON.stringify(values);

    alert(JSON.stringify(values));  // this alert will display above values

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'GPCreateCheque.aspx/setCheqVendorSearchEntry',
        data: JSON.stringify(values),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function (result) {
                    alert("Not save");
                }
    });
})
```

**WebMethod code**

```
public partial class WebForm5 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string setCheqVendorSearchEntry(vendorEntry[] values)
    {

        //here I will write the code to store the records in database

        return "Success";  //for testing I return this string
    }
}

public class vendorEntry{
    public string billno { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how to receive from ajax. Thanks

**Update Error msg**

```
http://localhost:55047/GPCreateCheque.aspx/setCheqVendorSearchEntry 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: And what's the error ? 404 page ? `venderEntrys` is null ?

Comment: @GGO `Status:500 Internal server error`

Comment: why are you converting json to string. pass it as json as data : values.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers How to pass and receive in server side, this kind of array value as json ?

Comment: error: function (result) { console.log(result); } check your browser console for exact error

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers I update the error message. It is internal server error

Comment: Have you tried changing this line `public static string setCheqVendorSearchEntry(vendorEntry[] values)` to `public static string setCheqVendorSearchEntry(string values)`?

Comment: @HaydenPassmore yes I tried the following things all `string values`,`string[] values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally make it run by following:

You need to make it allowed for POST method

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public static string setCheqVendorSearchEntry(vendorEntry[] values)
{
    return "Success";  //for testing I return this string
}
```

and Default.aspx, your Json Array was not proper. You need to take parameter name (here it is 'values' in setCheqVendorSearchEntry method) in json element and pass it as string or serialize.

```
 var values = '{ "values": [{ "billno": "111", "amount": "2233.00" }, { "billno": "222", "amount": "2500.00" }, { "billno": "333", "amount": "3000.00" }] }';

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'Default.aspx/setCheqVendorSearchEntry',
                        data: values,
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        }
                    });
```

For your learning purpose:

When you console your error in ajax error section, you can find exact error in browser console like this:
Image : https://prnt.sc/gw06sr

Comment: can I use like this `data: JSON.stringify(values)`?

Comment: yes you can use but you have to remove single quote from Json for that

Comment: which single quote you are telling.

Comment: var values = { "values": [{ "billno": "111", "amount": "2233.00" }, { "billno": "222", "amount": "2500.00" }, { "billno": "333", "amount": "3000.00" }] };

you can use like this

Comment: IF my solution works, you can up vote and accept it as answer

Comment: Hei Genius you are correct. Ok then How can I sperate the record from that array. please update that one also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156455/discussion-between-mohamed-faiz-and-ubiquitous-developers).